# How to pass DataTable as parameter in BLToolkit?

Tags: c#, .net, database, orm, bltoolkit

I get an error when I try to do this.

And here is my code.

```
public abstract void SaveSchedule(DataTable items);
```

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 1 ("@items"), row 0, column 0: Data type 0xF3 (user-defined table type) has a non-zero length database name specified.  Database name is not allowed with a table-valued parameter, only schema name and type name are valid

Answer (score 0):

You, probably, should drop TableName in table object

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.TableName = null;
repository.SaveSchedule(table);
```